Why are Dynamic Colors not working on my android 14?
I want to use dynamic colors in my app with java and I use
DynamicColors.applyToActivitiesIfAvailable(getApplication());

to apply them, but colors doesn't change as in my phone's other apps
except when I switch between light and dark mode and vice versa while in the app, I'm using a Redmi Note 13 Pro 5G running android 14, any help please?
Tried using
DynamicColors.applyToActivitiesIfAvailable(getApplication());

Expect to see colors match with screen wallpaper
But nothing happened except when I change phone theme

Did you find a solution?
